# operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[] in django?

Tags: django

models.py

```
 from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

 class Product(DateTimeModel):
          colors = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500),null=True, blank=True) # I am having => black,red
```

views.py

```
 def filters(request):
          price_filters = request.GET.getlist('price', default=None)  # from form ['300','1000',...]
          color_filters = request.GET.getlist('colors', default=None)  # from form ['red']
          total_filters = list(chain(price_filters,color_filters))
          products = Product.objects.filter(Q(colors__in=total_filters) | (Q( price__gt=total_filters)) # I know the gt expecting number but it comes with string and integers. so I get error
          print(products)
```

When I am performing this I am getting this error `ProgrammingError at /product/filter-query/   operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[]    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

How to perform this. please needed help.

**EDIT:**
I want to work with multiple filters at the same time. i.e. price range will be ['300'.'1000'] should be above this list. when performing this I got `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'gt' for PositiveIntegerField or join on the field not permitted, perhaps you meant gt or gte?`  how can I achieve this?.please add some tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your field `colors` is `text[]`, the array of strings. You are trying to use `IN` operator with a list of strings as a parameter. That obviously wouldn't work since elements of `text[]` is `text`.

You probably want to filter all products that overlap with given colors. If so, you should use [`overlap` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap):

```py
products = Product.objects.filter(colors__overlap=l)
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. can you please help me to solve another question associated with that? I updated with this question.

Comment: @sam we have a war in Ukraine against russia, so kinda busy.

Comment: Oh.Okay. We pray for Ukraine from India.